# Android - Switching between Multiple Views in a ViewFlipper

Tags: android, listview, view, viewflipper

I have an application using ListView inside Tabs, and i'd like to switch to a separate View(data collection widget) on clicking an item in the List.
I'm adding each List's row's children to a ViewFlipper and the items are added at runtime so there is no definite number of views. As such, i would want to navigate/switch to a particular View in the ViewFlipper.
Any pointers?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: be specific. your question is very broad.

Comment: Ok, to be specific,I have a ListView where each row has another unique View/Data collection widget(A textfield + textarea). When you click on an item on the ListView, it should take you to a View associated with that Row. My question is, is it possible then to navigate to a particular view in a ViewFlipper maybe based on an ID of some sort?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks guys.
I have worked around the ViewFlipper setDisplayedChild() method and it works perfectly in my scenario.

```
myViews.setDisplayedChild(pos);
```

pos being the ID of the View I want to switch to.

Answer (score 2):

> there is no definite number of views.

Very bad approach to add infinite views for a ViewFlipper. Try to add only one, and when an list item is selected refresh the **only** view and bring it up.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I think we had to put in the viewflipper the current view, and the next view we want to display, and call the method shownext() (or showprevious()).

Comment: Thank you Muniu, it's works fine for the flip! But with your solution, the view flipper is no longer center is his parent even if I define it in the xml layout...
Is someone have an idea?